# DirectoryEntry (0x80005000)

Tags: c#, powershell, ldap, directoryentry, powerview

```
string strPath = "LDAP://" + dcip;
DirectoryEntry de;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                de = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
            }
            else
            {
                de = new DirectoryEntry(strPath, username, password);
            }
            

DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
deSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=domainDNS)";
deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
SearchResult result = deSearch.FindOne();
return result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
```

this can run in the domain user's cmd,
but when run it in the system privilege's cmd，it return the error

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): 未知错误(0x80005000)
   在 System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   在 System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   在 System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   在 System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   在 System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

the powerview.ps1 use the same code with it,but powerview can run in the domain user's cmd and also the system privilege cmd

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as (properly formatted) text

Comment: Maybe check the permission

Comment: the computer account has privilege to do ldap query

Answer (score 0):

I hava found the bug!
In my code,`dcip = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN");`
But the env USERDNSDOMAIN is not same between the user and the system

Comment: So, the problem is solved now? Please consider deleting this question then, because nowhere in the post is shown where line `dcip = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN")` fits in the code..